# Check Ubuntu for Installation Issues/Errors

Tags: ubuntu, installation, upgrade, ubuntu-13.04

I upgraded from Ubuntu 12.10 to 13.04. I have got an error massage before the upgrade was finished and now i have the feeling that Ubuntu 13.04 was not installed correctly. How can i check/scan the OS for errors ? I dual boot with Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest I'm not aware of any utility to scan for installation errors, but if you are experiencing some weird behaviour from the OS, you could try to reinstall the `ubuntu-desktop` metapackage, it should reinstall everything that may be lost/damaged during the upgrade.

I'm using Kubuntu, and sometimes when I get problems in updating the files of the KDE environment, reinstalling `kubuntu-desktop` (which, as you can guess, is the equivalent to `ubuntu-desktop` for Kubuntu) solves anything.

Anyway, from a more general point of view, I found that when making major version upgrades, it is better to use a LiveCD, rather than using the built-in upgrade options, it causes far less problems; if you have your /home folder on a separate partition, you won't lose any data, and you simply have to reinstall some software.

You can also check [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5466/is-a-clean-install-better-than-upgrading) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138842/upgrade-vs-clean-install-without-formatting).

Comment: So if i burn Ubuntu 13.04 on Live CD there are no options on the CD to check the OS for Errors ? Maybe i should uninstall the OS and then install it again but this time with Live-CD. I will try also your suggestion with Ubuntu-desktop. I am a new user with Ubuntu how can i uninstall and then install Ubuntu-Desktop ?

Comment: You don't need to uninstall it, you can simply use `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` and it should do it by itself.

Comment: Ok i will try it now. So i do not need to re-install the whole OS just using "sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop" will do the trick and correct the errors if there are any ? I just want to be sure.

Comment: Usually reinstalling that package solve any problem, so before reinstalling the whole system, try it and see if the system behaves correctly. If you keep experiencing problems, you can reinstall everything later. And usually, you won't need to do that either, because a malfunction of a possibly corrupted package installation can be solved by simply reinstall the said package with no need to reinstall everything.

Comment: And if you are new to Ubuntu, I suggest you to check out the [Ubuntu Community Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community) and [Ubuntu Guide](http://ubuntuguide.org/), they are full of useful informations.

Comment: One more question, can i see somewhere the error i got before the end of the upgrade. Are these errors somewhere stored ?

Comment: On Linux (hence on Ubuntu too) system logs are stored on the `/var/log` directory. You can directly open them (they are simple text files) or use a viewer, in your case I guess it would be "Gnome System Log". Also read [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/186276/where-are-all-the-major-log-files-located)